# why redirect() doesn't work within if statement , how can i execute it within if statement?? in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

1. after execute this function i see just white page , no thing
2. this function for Sorting posts by category , state , municipal.

```
public function sorting_posts(Request $R){

  if( (!is_null($R->state) AND is_null($R->municipal) ) AND is_null($R->type) ){
    $Posts = Post::latest('created_at')
    ->where('state_id',$R->state)
    ->where('category_id',$R->category_id)
    ->paginate(9);

    return redirect()->route('by.category',$R->category_id)->with('Posts',$Posts);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not executed because it doesn't met the condition. You can try dd to check whether it passed the condition or not

Comment: second question would be why are you redirecting at all? seems like you should be returning a view or some data instead of redirecting and flashing a paginated collection to the session